# Preserve textbox Values on session timeout asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

My problem is very straight forward. see steps:

1. logged in.
2. open form, type text on textboxes and wait for session time out.
3. control would redirect to login page, and when typed valid username and password
4. All the typed text would be reset.

I want to preserve the values of textboxes.

can anyone tell Me? I am using sqlserver as session state.

Edited: I do have multiple forms, and Radio buttons, checkboxes dropdown selection also.I need centralized solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell your users to complete forms faster?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ASP.Net Profile (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) to store values entered in the textBoxes and restore those values upon relogging.

Comment: I do have multiple forms, and Radio buttons, checkboxes dropdown selection also. I need centralized solution.

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer: Tell your users to complete forms faster.

Harder answer: You wouldn't be able to easily store the form values in Session/Profile because if they never submit the form, the server will never see the values. I suppose you could do a background ajax post before they submit the form.

Another option is to increase the timeouts for [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx), and [application pool recycling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Do an ajax post and save the content in persistant data source (your DB) in certain intervals.  Something like google docs does.

Answer (score 0):

**Option1** : Do periodic data save to the DB using Ajax.

**Option2**:  Show a warning to user about data loss when it is about to expire the session.

**Option3**:  Not good way but, to hold the data periodically until it is saved in Cache object.